# How to concatenate lines that match a pattern?

Tags: linux, perl, unix, sed, awk

I have a huge file where most lines are long, but there are a few lines that are just a few words:

```
Here is a long sentence.
This
is
a
short
line.
Here is a long sentence.
Here is a long sentence.
This
is
another
short
line.
Here is a long sentence.
```

All short lines begin with unique words. In this example, short lines begin with "This" and end with "line." And they span exactly the same number of lines. I need a command that will concatenate *only* the short lines in the file, so that I get

```
Here is a long sentence.
This is a short line.
Here is a long sentence.
Here is a long sentence.
This is another short line.
Here is a long sentence.
```

Is there a command that will do the job? I don't want to write a script program if I don't have to...

Thanks.

Comment: Can "long" lines definitely NOT begin with "This"?

Comment: When you say `All short lines begin with unique words.` do you instead mean `All short lines begin with a single word.`? You need to post some more representative input and expected output.

Comment: Please try this module [to split English sentences](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomoy/Lingua-EN-Sentence-0.25/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm)

Comment: Apologies for not specifying the problem clearly. (I was trying to be succinct). I mean that all sets of lines that I want to concatenate begin with the same keyword (e.g., "This"), and span the same number of lines. And the lines that I don't want to concatenate, those lines do NOT begin with that keyword. Put another way, each time I encounter the word, "This", I want to concatenate that line w/ the next 4 lines.

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -pe's/\n/ / if ($j ||= /^This$/) &&= !/^line\.$/'
```

Usage:

```
perl -pe'...' file.in >file.out    # From file
perl -pe'...' <file.in >file.out   # From STDIN
perl -i~ -pe'...' file             # "In-place" with backup
perl -i -pe'...' file              # "In-place" without backup
```

Comment: Why use 'This' and 'line' if all sentences end with a period?  Could you just replace all CR/LFs with a single space, then replace '\.' with '\.\n'?  This assumes we want one sentence per line.

Comment: @Jim Black, Because I chose to follow the specs instead of making unfounded assumptions.

Comment: To late, 'In this example, ...'.

Comment: @Jim Black, If you have a problem with my solution because the identifying factor wasn't stated clearly enough, imagine what that means about your suggestion to use an identifying factor that wasn't mentioned at all!

Comment: @Jim Black, Nowhere does he say he's looking to place a sentence per line, and even if that's what he wanted, looking for "`.`" is an awful way of identifying sentences.

Comment: Which is why I suggested to use Lingua::EN::Sentence in the first place.  Lines are input, sentences are output.  Said matching pattern could have been 'lines that don't end in a period'.  Said module would work for most English text.

Comment: @Jim Black, No, you suggested to "replace all CR/LFs with a single space, then replace '\.' with '\.\n'". And again, that assumes the OP wants a sentence per line despite no mention on that anywhere in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e :a -e '/line\.$/{p;d;}' -e '/^This/{N;s/\n/ /g;};ta' file.in > file.out
```